# How to count the number of occurence of string in Splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I am not able to find a Splunk query to count the number of occurences of a string across events.

My string is:

```
"\"IsFeedback\":true"
```

I tried this but it doesn't count the number of occurrences of the string across events:

```
host="HOST001" AND "\"IsFeedback\":true"
```

I want the occurrence of `"\"IsFeedback\":true"` across all events.

Comment: Does it return an incorrect count? No results?

Comment: @reginold :  it returns me the same result as it does with out STATS COUNTS. I want to get the count of the string across all events, like a string count. In one event i have multiple count of the same string.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
index=xxxx sourcetype=xxxx host="HOST001" "\"IsFeedback\":true" | stats count
```

Comment: this caps @ 10,000